# How to replicate this very specific SUMIFS example in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I need to do a SUMIFS, basically what I need is the column highlighted in yellow below that sums UnitPrice based on the OrderNo and WorkCntr columns:

[image]

The SUMIFS code is right next to it, in Excel. it's quite easy, not sure how I can translate to SQL.  I saw that CASE statements work like SUMIFS, but I haven't been able to figure it out.  Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT
  r.OrderNo,
  r.JobNo,
  r.PartNo,
  r.WorkCntr,
  r.ActualPcsGood,
  o.UnitPrice,
CASE
  WHEN r.WorkCntr = 'Cutting' AND r.OrderNo = '10426' THEN SUM(o.UnitPrice)
  ELSE NULL
  END AS [Total $ per WC per Order]
FROM OrderDet o JOIN OrderRouting r ON o.JobNo = r.JobNo
WHERE r.OrderNo = '10426'
GROUP BY  r.OrderNo, r.JobNo, r.PartNo, r.WorkCntr, r.ActualPcsGood, 
o.UnitPrice
ORDER BY 1, 4;
```

The result of this code is the first 7 columns of my table above.  Basically it's returning the same value, not the SUM of.  Now ideally, I shouldn't have to specify the order number and work center outside of the WHERE clause, as in Excel, you just drag and the formula is always reading the OrderNo and WorkCntr fields for that particular row.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Well maybe easy on excel if you can see the columns names, picture doesn't show any so we cant understand the formula.

Comment: OrderNo is on cell A1, forgot to include that.  Column F is UnitPrice, Column D is WorkCntr, and Column A is OrderNo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the function you are looking for is a windowing function, but I understand how CASE WHEN would seem like a good choice (and it could work when combined with SUM, but not efficiently). Try replace your  CASE WHEN statement with:

```
SUM(UnitPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY r.orderNumber,r.WorkCntr) as  [Total $ per WC per Order]
```